# VBA add Formula to cells containing specific text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add a lookup formula to cells in a range where the word YES appears and leave the text in all other cells in the range as they are. My code is.

```
Sub AddFormula()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("B1:B20")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Yes") > 0 Then
        cel.Value = "=VLOOKUP(A1,H:I,2,0)"

    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Unfortunately the cell reference 'A1' does not change as the formula is entered. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution to get the cell left to cel instead of always A1:

```
Sub AddFormula()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("B1:B20")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Yes") > 0 Then
        cel.Value = "=VLOOKUP(A" & cel.Row & ",H:I,2,0)"
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code doesnt look like it's supposed to change values in 'A1'. The loop is over cells in B1:B20, so only cells in B1:B20 can change. Maybe you are not getting any changes expected because your if condition is never true? 
I would suggest using the Immediate Window to check if the if condition is ever true with "Debug.print. Also better to use R1C1 references like this:

```
Sub AddFormula()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("B1:B20")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Yes") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Was true"
            cel.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[6]:C[7],2,0)"
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Can you explain how the RC[-1] works please? I'm still learning this stuff. Thanks.